# Using screenshot as og:image cached too soon when sharing with LinkedIn

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I want to display a screenshot of the page as og:image. The site is customized WP and for generating screenshots I'm using free WP service MSHOTS.

In my functions.php file, I've disabled og:image output generated by a plugin

```
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image' , '__return_false' );
```

and added another function to generate screenshot from page and use it as og:image

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_screenshot_as_ogimage' );

function add_screenshot_as_ogimage(){

echo '<meta property="og:image" content="https://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ).'?w=1200"/>';  
}
```

The problem is, when page is loaded, screenshot is being generated but it doesn't happen instantly. It usually takes about 30 seconds for screenshot to be generated. During that 30 seconds, there is only black image visible with text "Generating Preview".

Unfortunately, that's the image LinkedIn grabs for sharing.

So I've tried adding an optional code to prime WP.com cache

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_screenshot_as_ogimage_footer' );

function add_screenshot_as_ogimage_footer(){
//prime WP.com cache to get the image and not a loading screen
echo '<img src="https://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/'.urlencode( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ).'?w=1200" width="1" height="1" style="visibility: hidden;">';
}
```

But still no luck. I also tried adding a php `sleep()` function before first action, but then the whole page doesn't load for the time set in function.

Also, weird thing is that Google+ and Facebook are able to grab the generated preview as og:image just fine. Only LinkedIn is giving me this troubles.

Is there any workaround for this, is it possible to set a delay before LinkedIn (or all crawlers) visit the page? I realize that LinkedIn clears its cache every couple of days, but that doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: No, there is no way to instruct any crawler to respect such an arbitrary delay. Are you rendering this screenshot on every page load? Should rather be done once (or once after page was updated), and then cached on your end to begin with.

Comment: I believe that it's being rendered on every page load. I'm forced to use MSHOTS service, even though I wanted to go with Phantomjs where I could render only once and cache it on my end.

Comment: That is bad. Not only does it cause your current problem - but presumably each request to this API will also cause another request to your site (because that service must request your page first, to create a thumbnail of it - and I wouldn’t just assume that they do caching on their end.) So in the worst case, you are actually doubling your traffic here - every page visit by a human visitor will cause a second one by that service.

Comment: I solved the problem by writing new functions which generate the screenshot via WP API, then I'm uploading and storing the screenshot in WP media library and then assigning that screenshot as the featured image with another function.